# Python passing object by reference confusion

Tags: python, arrays, function, object, pass-by-reference

Hi I seem to having issues understanding of passing object by reference in Python. I understand example 1 output, but shouldn't example 2 behave in the similar way and not change the A matrix?

## Example 1:

```
def reassign(list):
  list = [0, 1, 2]

list = [3]
reassign(list)
print(list)

Returns: [3]
```

## Example 2:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((4,4))

def xyz(A):
    for i in range(4):
        A[i,i] = 0    
    return None

x = xyz(A)
print(A)

# Returns

[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing by reference means that, when you pass a variable into the function, you don't pass the variable *itself*, you pass the *pointer to* the variable, which is *copied* from outside to inside the function. In Example 1, you pass `list` into the function, which is a pointer to a list that contains the elements `[3]`. But then, immediately after, you take that variable holding the pointer to the list, and put a new pointer in it, to a new list that contains the elements `[0, 1, 2]`. Note that you *haven't changed the list you started with* - you changed what *the variable referring to it* referred to. And when you get back out of the function, the variable you passed into the function (still a pointer to the first list) hasn't changed - it's still pointing to a list that contains the elements `[3]`.

In Example 2, you pass `A` into `xyz()`. Whereas in Example 1 you did something along the lines of

```
A = something_else
```

here, you're doing

```
A[i] = something_else
```

This is an *entirely different operation* - instead of changing what the variable holding the list is pointing to, you're changing the list itself - by changing one of its elements. Instead of making `A` point to something else, you're changing the value that `A` points to by dereferencing it.